# Random sampling with Hypothesis

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, random, python-hypothesis

In Hypothesis, there is an [corresponding `sampled_from()` strategy](http://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#choices) to [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
In [1]: from hypothesis import find, strategies as st

In [2]: find(st.sampled_from(('ST', 'LT', 'TG', 'CT')), lambda x: True)
Out[2]: 'ST'
```

But, is there a way to have [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)-like strategy to produce subsequences of length N out of a sequence?

```
In [3]: import random

In [4]: random.sample(('ST', 'LT', 'TG', 'CT'), 2)
Out[4]: ['CT', 'TG']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
permutations(elements).map(lambda x: x[:n])
```

Comment: Is it supposed to return a random permutation of size n? I have tried following: `find(st.permutations([1,2,3,4,5]).map(lambda x: x[:2]), lambda x: True)` . But it is always returning `[1,2]`.

Comment: `find` always returns minimised examples, not random ones. Hypothesis doesn't support interactive random generation like that.

Answer (score 1):

It feels like this should be possible with the `lists` strategy, but I couldn't make it work. By aping the [`sampled_from`](https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis-python/blob/3.5.1/src/hypothesis/strategies.py#L400-L418) code, I was able to make something that seems to work.

```
from random import sample
from hypothesis.searchstrategy.strategies import SearchStrategy
from hypothesis.strategies import defines_strategy


class SampleMultipleFromStrategy(SearchStrategy):
    def __init__(self, elements, n):
        super(SampleMultipleFromStrategy, self).__init__()
        self.elements = tuple(elements)
        if not self.elements:
            raise ValueError
        self.n = int(n)

    def do_draw(self, data):
        return sample(self.elements, self.n)

@defines_strategy
def sample_multiple_from(elements, n):
    return SampleMultipleFromStrategy(elements, n)
```

Sample result:

```
>>> find(sample_multiple_from([1, 2, 3, 4], 2), lambda x: True)
[4, 2]
```

Comment: Please don't do it this way.

a) Inheriting from SearchStrategy is an internal API. The inheritance structure isn't stable.
b) Using random methods inside a strategy will work ish but won't minimize properly.